# Generator functions in express with bluebird and co

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, generator, ecmascript-6

I'm trying out some of the harmony features in node 0.12, in particular trying out the new generators feature. I'm doing this with co (v4), bluebird and express (v4), something like this:

```
 // ...
var fs = bluebird.promisifyAll(require('fs'));

// ...
app.post('/test', co.wrap(function* (req, res, next) {
    var contents = yield fs.readFileAsync('/etc/hosts', 'utf8');
    return res.send(contents);
}));
// ...
```

According to its documentation, co.wrap returns a normal function that returns a promise from the given generator function.

This is working fine so far, but what I'm not sure is if a) I'm leaking memory by not 'waiting' for the returned promise's result and b) If I might lose an exception thrown in my generator function, or one of the modules used by it.

Is this a good approach? Do you see anything wrong with it?.

Comment: Does `app.post` expect to await the asynchronous result of your callback somehow?

Comment: app.post is express' app.post. So, I suppose it doesn't (?)

Comment: It's pointless to use `co` if you're using bluebird since bluebird ships with `Promise.coroutine` which is a more powerful and robust version of `co` anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that if your generator function will throw some exception, it will not be passed to next middleware. So you will lose it. You can use bluebird's [`Promise.coroutine`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisecoroutinegeneratorfunction-generatorfunction---function) function to implement your own simple `co` wrapper, which will be working well in express:

```js
// module: ../helpers/co.js
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var co      = Promise.coroutine;

module.exports = function(gen) {
    var coGen = co(gen);

    function handle_error(err, req, res, next) {
        return coGen.apply(this, arguments).catch(next);
    }

    function handle_request(req, res, next) {
        return coGen.apply(this, arguments).catch(next);
    }

    return gen.length > 3 ? handle_error : handle_request;
};
```

**UPD**: I have changed the realization a little. Now it takes into account the number or arguments passed into the generator: if > 3 then error handler will be used, otherwise - request handler. It's important for express (look in the source code [here](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/4.12.3/lib/router/layer.js#L52) and [here](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/4.12.3/lib/router/layer.js#L76))

Now you can use it in your code:

```
// module: your/router.js

// ...
var co = require('../helpers/co');    
var fs = bluebird.promisifyAll(require('fs'));

// ...
app.post('/test', co(function* (req, res, next) {
    var contents = yield fs.readFileAsync('/etc/hosts', 'utf8');
    return res.send(contents);
}));
// ...
```

**UPD** This is solution for express with version <= 4.x. Most likely express 5.x [will support promises](https://github.com/strongloop/express/pull/2237), so you'll can use just bluebird's `Promis.coroutine` without any fancy wrappers:

```
// module: your/router.js

// ...
var fs = bluebird.promisifyAll(require('fs'));
var co = bluebird.coroutine;    

// ...
app.post('/test', co(function*(req, res, next) {
    var contents = yield fs.readFileAsync('/etc/hosts', 'utf8');
    return res.send(contents);
}));
// ...
```

Comment: In general - the second approach is much better than your first one since it only calls `Promise.coroutine` once - `Promise.coroutine` is meant to only be called in initialisation time.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Actually, in both approaches it was calling `Promise.coroutine` on every request. Now it calls only once. Thanks for comment! Also I added remark about future versions of express.