# how to use bluebird or co coroutines in express router (for yielding controller functions and error handling)?

Tags: node.js, rest, mongoose, bluebird, coroutine

I what to use features that described here: [sync-error-handling-expressjs-es7-promises-generators](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/async-error-handling-expressjs-es7-promises-generators/) . I'm writing API for my app, how could i do something like this? I'm trying to find example or some explanations.

Comment: It's unclear what your question means.  The document you reference shows all sorts of coding examples and explains how to do it. What part of that document do you not understand or are asking for help with?  Please be very specific what you're asking for.  Your current question is both too unclear and too broad for stack overflow and will be downvoted or closed if not corrected.  Since you may be new here, I'd suggest you read [How do I ask a good question on stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and study that.

Comment: @jfriend00 ,  i want to find some examples about how to use coroutines in express routing ( with middleware, controller). For example - i'm trying to get something with mongoose then yield its response, and then something with response. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29189243/5472180) something explained here, but i want any more complex example. Can i yield mongoose req inside middleware, that checks for userAuth, how? i want ti yield middleware check >send next err if err or user not authorised> if authorised - perform another yield

Comment: Then, edit your question to show a specific example of what you want to do.  Your question just doesn't show enough of what you're trying to do for anyone to know how to answer.  3hrs with no answer on stack overflow means your question is not clear.  If it was clear, there would typically be multiple answers by now for something related to Javascript.